# Android finish() ends app instead of going to onAcitivityResult of previous activity

Tags: android

I am trying to get some data from a server. User clicks search and another acitivity starts by startActivityForResult().when user clicks the data the data should be put inside intent and setResult() is done with that intent and finish() is called. Now i have tried debugg but when finish() is called the activity does no go back to the one which called this activity. instead the app closes down.

Here is the code;

```
public class SearchContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar pb;
    CircleImageView profile_image_search;
    TextView name_search,user_name_search;
    EditText edit_search_contact;
    Button btn_search_contact;
    ConstraintLayout cl;
    String profile_image,firstName,lastName;
    RequestQueue myQueue;
    String url = "working url";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_contact);

        pb = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        profile_image_search = findViewById(R.id.profile_image_search);
        name_search = findViewById(R.id.name_search);
        user_name_search = findViewById(R.id.user_name_search);
        btn_search_contact = findViewById(R.id.btn_search_contact);
        edit_search_contact = findViewById(R.id.edit_search_contact);
        cl = findViewById(R.id.nested_layout);

        cl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResultForPreviousAcitvity();
            }
        });
        btn_search_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    search_contacts();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        hideVisibility();
    }
    public void setResultForPreviousAcitvity()
    {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("first_name",firstName);
        data.putExtra("last_name",lastName);
        data.putExtra("user_name",user_name_search.getText().toString());
        data.putExtra("profile", profile_image);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
        finish(); // app closes down here
    }
    private void search_contacts() throws JSONException {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //send php data in json array format
        //JSONObject jsonbody = new JSONObject("{\"search_key\":\"jhonsanders \"}");
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("search_key", edit_search_contact.getText().toString().trim());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( url,new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject myobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        firstName = myobj.getString("first_name");
                        lastName = myobj.getString("last_name");
                        String userName = myobj.getString("user_name");
                        profile_image = myobj.getString("profile_image");
                        Bitmap image = NameAndImage.stringToImage(profile_image);
                        show_visibility();
                        profile_image_search.setImageBitmap(image);
                        user_name_search.setText(userName);
                        name_search.setText(firstName+" "+lastName);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        })/*{
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("search_key",edit_search_contact.getText().toString().trim());
                return param;
            }
        }*/;
        myQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(SearchContactActivity.this).getRequestQueue();
        myQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
    private void hideVisibility()
    {
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        profile_image_search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        name_search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        user_name_search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
    private void show_visibility()
    {
        profile_image_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        name_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        user_name_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
   /* private Bitmap stringToImage(String s)
    {
        byte[] image = Base64.decode(s,Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);
        return decodedImage;
    }*/

}
```

The above activity is called by

```
Intent i = new Intent(ContactsActivity.this,SearchContactActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CONTACT_SEARCH);
```

This is the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.privatechat">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PrivateChat">
        <activity android:name=".SearchContactActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ContactsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".NameAndImage" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

There is no logs that i can print.The log is cleared when onfinish() is called.

The app goes back to this other activity. This one also has onAcitivityResult but its not the one that called the other acitivity.

```
public class NameAndImage extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editFirstName,editLastName;
    ImageView profile_image;
    Button uploadNameImage;
    Bitmap image;
    RequestQueue myQueue;
    SaveSharedPreference sp = new SaveSharedPreference();

    private String URL = "working url";
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1011;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name_and_image);
        editFirstName = findViewById(R.id.edit_first_name);
        editLastName = findViewById(R.id.edit_last_name);
        profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image_search);
        uploadNameImage = findViewById(R.id.upload_name_image);
        Log.i("SharedPreference",sp.getUserName(NameAndImage.this).trim());

        profile_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickPhoto();
            }
        });

        uploadNameImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadData();
            }
        });
    }
    private void pickPhoto()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
    private  void uploadData()
    {
        StringRequest upload_data = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(response.trim().equals("success_data_upload"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(NameAndImage.this, "upload success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(NameAndImage.this,ContactsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        if(response.trim().equals("Error"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(NameAndImage.this, "upload error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("server",response.toString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(NameAndImage.this, "Response dont match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("server",response);
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(NameAndImage.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("server",error.toString());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("image",imageToString(image));
                param.put("first_name",editFirstName.getText().toString());
                param.put("last_name",editLastName.getText().toString());
                param.put("user_name",sp.getUserName(NameAndImage.this).trim());
                return param;
            }
        };
        upload_data.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                3000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
        ));
        myQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(NameAndImage.this).getRequestQueue();
        myQueue.add(upload_data);
    }
    public static String imageToString(Bitmap pic)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imageByte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imageByte,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    public static Bitmap stringToImage(String s)
    {
        byte[] image = Base64.decode(s,Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);
        return decodedImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uri);
                profile_image.setImageBitmap(image);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
The app seems to close but after 2 sec the wrong activity is started.

Comment: I think you are using the flag SingleTop on the manifest. Can you add the <activity> section of the manifest?

Comment: i have added the manifest. There is no SingleTop

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any `finish()` in your first Activity when launching the second one ? It seems that the Backstack is clear...

Comment: if you want any data from one activity to a back activity use always broadcast services or interface that will be good

Comment: @Bruno i dont have finish() in the activity which starts the second one

Comment: *if you want any data from one activity to a back activity use always broadcast services or interface that will be good* **this is obviously terrible solution** ... it would not work when you fx rotate screen ... you should always act like there is only one living activity

Comment: Check the log cat, maybe the app has crashed ! it doesn't relate to finish !

Comment: @TheMJ There is nothing about crash in logcat

Comment: @Selvin i am sorry i dont quite understand. Are you saying my solution is terrible or the one the other person proposed?

Comment: the citeted comment is terrible solution

Comment: you start `ContactsActivity` and you added the code of the `SearchContactActivity` ?

Comment: @ShayKin no i am starting SearchContactAcitivity.

Comment: i can,t see it on you code

Answer (score 0):

When setting the result in setResult() i was putting a string profile which contained image as a String. I guess the string was really large but when i debugg the whole string seemed to be there. So when i made profile empty the app operated normally. Looks like i will have to split the string in 2 for more effectiveness.